# Fading shade for ImageView border

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How to achieve this in android? Any better ways[Fading shade border for imageview,imagebutton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfaeU.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a free design/coding nor debugging service, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own drawable to achieve this.

The code for your Border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Implement this in your layout by using `android:background="@drawable/border"`.

Android also has some options.

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
```

You could also use websites like http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/ to achieve it. Here is tutorial for 9Patch: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/