# Adding black outline shadow to drawables

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

In popular apps like snaphat and facebook, whenever there is a view that has dynamic content with icons - they are usually outlined in a slight black shadow to help with visibility.

How do I achieve this?

Before someone says this was done in photoshop, I opened the image in an editor and found that its not an exact outline (its an actual shadow that fades into the background) which makes me highly doubt this was a modification done in photoshop/gimp

[image]

Comment: what do you want , means can you explain briefly because i don't understand your question

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44841442/7461132). Hope it solves your question.

Comment: @Abhi hey abhi, thanks for your response. Could you reply below with an actual answer demonstrating your step with a vector icon - so that I can accept it as an answer if it is correct? (I'm relatively new and although I understand your explanation - have trouble transfering the same technique from a rectangle shape to an actual variable vector)

Comment: If the shadow (gradient) is part of the image, it's part of the image. So someone, with some tool (could well have been photoshop or gimp or fireworks or whatever) has added that shadow to the image. It's not created programmatically.

Comment: see [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/fe09aacd259f5cb050aa22691b294f1b/raw/587e7211e6a87bbd1d5a66dbc54529683842e044/S.java)